# How to get image from different package in java with ClassLoader

Tags: java, image, swing, nullpointerexception, classloader

[image]

```
class AA extends JPanel{

String path = "src/diff/images/image2.png";
JLabel image = null; 

public AA() {
    setLayout(null);
    setBounds(0,0,200,400);
    setBackground(Color.black);
    
    image = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ClassLoader.getSystemResource(path)));
    image.setBounds(0,0,200,400);
    add(image);
}
}
```

Results in a `NullPointerException` 
I tried to change the path `"/src/diff/images/image2.png"`,
but it yield the same result.

Comment: Your resources, like images, should be stored in folders connected to the project, not src.  In your example lect_gui.  Make sure your resources folders are on the classpath.

Comment: You should probably not use `get*System*Resource`, but instead `getResource`. Also, you need the leading '/' and fully qualified name to load resources from a different package.

Comment: Does your project is a `maven` project?